# Выборка данных с помощью LinqToSql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq2sql

Здравствуйте. Не так давно начал изучать entity framework и linq to sql. Не всё ещё понимаю. Пытаюсь сделать выборку вот таким вот запросом:

```
Subjects s = db.Subjects.Where(q => q.Name == comboBox1.Text);
```

Ругается:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'Questioning.Models.Subjects'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Но при этом если делаю это всё в блоке `foreach`, тогда всё нормально:

```
foreach(Subjects q in db.Subjects.Where(q => q.Name == comboBox1.Text))
                {

                }
```

В чём разница? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы правда не можете отличить последовательность элементов от одного элемента?

Comment: @PavelMayorov могу, но мне нужно вытащить всего лишь 1 элемент, и я не как не могу понять почему это не работает без цикла

Comment: Один элемент в Linq - `FirstOrDefault();`. В вашем случае вы получаете коллекцию. В первом варианте для теста поменяйте в самом начале Subjects на var и наведите на название, гляньте какой тип получит ваша `s`.

Comment: если элемент должен быть только один, то есть методы `Single` и `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: Просто сравните что возвращает правая часть присваивания и какой тип вы написали слева

Comment: @FoggyFinder а вы не могли бы показать пример относительно моего первого выражения, как бы это выглядело с `SingleOrDefault`. Не разу не использовал его. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: `Subjects s = db.Subjects.SingleOrDefault(q => q.Name == comboBox1.Text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод Where возвращает **всегда** IEnumerable  даже если результат - это один элемент. По этому работает foreach и не работает первый запрос.

Если Вы  уверены, что на выходе точно должен быть один элемент то сделайте так:

```
Subjects s = db.Subjects.Where(q => q.Name == comboBox1.Text).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Where тогда уж можно выкинуть, а предикат перенести в First

Answer (score -2):

Subjects - это DbSet< YourType> .Он НЕ реализует интерфейс IQueryable.
А в вашем коде происходит неявное приведение IQueryable< YourType > к DbSet< YourType >, отсюда и исключение. В таком случае вы можете сделать следующее:

1 Вариант:

```
var s = db.YourType.Where(q => q.Name == comboBox1.Text); // как по мне лучший вариант
```

2 Вариант:

```
IQueryable<YourType> = db.YourType.Where(q => q.Name == comboBox1.Text);
```

А что насчет foreach. Так в foreach(var item in YourCollection), item имеет тип элемента из коллекции, которую вы перебираете. Использую LINQ вы получаете на выходе IQuerylable или IEnumerable, которые поддерживает Foreach, что позволяет читать коллекцию, но тут важно помнить, что при использовании foreach нельзя добавлять или удалять элементы из коллекции внутри цикла, т.к это ломает итератор. Но это уже тема для другой статьи:)